# ¿Como puedo ingresar un if exists dentro de un select de sql?

Tags: sql-server, condiciones, sql, exists

Me gustaría la forma correcta de saber si un proyecto existe dentro de una consulta para en base a ese resultado de si existe aplicar acciones y si no existe aplicar otras nuevas acciones.

Código de SQL:

```
SELECT  NEWID(),r.Proyecto, r.Importe,r.ClaseCoste,r.FechaCorte,r.NumHoras,r.Proveedor,
r.TipoServicio,r.FolioSantec,r.Ambiente, r.Tecnologia, case  when r.Ambiente='PRE' then r.NumHoras*m.TarifaOLC else 

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM db_Incurrido.dbo.GSE_Real gse WHERE gse.Proyecto =r.proyecto) 
BEGIN
   SELECT 1 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 2
END

 end ImporteOLC
              FROM db_Incurrido.dbo.GSE_Real r (nolock)
           left outer join  db_Incurrido.dbo.FYCG_Migracion_TarifaMedia m (nolock) on r.FolioSantec = m.Proyecto;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes poner un IF dentro de un SELECT. Para eso existe CASE que ya estás usando y sólo necesitas continuar agregando condiciones. Un poco de formato tampoco cae mal.

```
SELECT  NEWID(),
    r.Proyecto, 
    r.Importe,
    r.ClaseCoste,
    r.FechaCorte,
    r.NumHoras,
    r.Proveedor,
    r.TipoServicio,
    r.FolioSantec,
    r.Ambiente, 
    r.Tecnologia, 
    CASE  WHEN r.Ambiente='PRE' THEN r.NumHoras*m.TarifaOLC 
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM db_Incurrido.dbo.GSE_Real gse WHERE gse.Proyecto =r.proyecto) THEN 1 
        ELSE 2 END AS ImporteOLC
FROM db_Incurrido.dbo.GSE_Real r 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  db_Incurrido.dbo.FYCG_Migracion_TarifaMedia m ON r.FolioSantec = m.Proyecto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Dejame ver si entendi tu pregunta:

```
    declare @existeProyecto int=0; 

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM db_Incurrido.dbo.GSE_Real gse WHERE gse.Proyecto =r.proyecto) 
    BEGIN
       Set @existeProyecto=1
    END

    ---tu variable existe proyecto  te dira si ejecutas uno u otro.

    IF  @existeProyecto=1

    BEGIN
      ---ejecuteas el select 1

    end
    else
    begin
      --ejecutas el segundo select 
    end
```

Como el resultado no depende o no influye en tu consulta principal el resultado lo guardas en otra variable, y esa variable la agregas a tu consulta principal,
de esta manera es mas legible tu consulta.

```
SELECT  NEWID(),r.Proyecto, r.Importe,r.ClaseCoste,r.FechaCorte,r.NumHoras,r.Proveedor,
r.TipoServicio,r.FolioSantec,r.Ambiente, r.Tecnologia, ...
```

Comment: Creo que no viste que es una subconsulta correlacionada. Al ponerla en un IF pierdes la relación con la consulta principal.